# LateInitializationError: Field 'avatar' has not been initialized flutter

Tags: flutter, initialization, lazy-initialization, dart-null-safety, dio

Below is how my json looks like

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "floki@mail.com",
        "first_name": "Valjakudze",
        "last_name": "shipment",
        "avatar": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Circle-icons-profile.svg/1024px-Circle-icons-profile.svg.png"
    }
}
```

I am using Dio and below are my two classes for the responses

Response Class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:json_crud/classes/user.dart';
part 'user_response.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserResponse{

  @JsonKey(name: "data")
  User? user;

  UserResponse();

  factory UserResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserResponseToJson(this);

}
```

Below is my UserClass

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User{

  @JsonKey(name: "id")
  late int id;

  @JsonKey(name: "email")
  late String email;

  @JsonKey(name: "first_name")
  late String firstName;

  @JsonKey(name: "last_name")
  late String lastName;

  @JsonKey(name: "avatar")
  late String avatar;

  User();

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

}
```

Below is my UserProfileScreen where i am supposed to set text

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_crud/classes/user.dart';
import 'package:json_crud/classes/user_response.dart';
import 'package:json_crud/http_service.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {

  const UserProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}

class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {

  HttpService? httpService;

  UserResponse? userResponse;

  User? user;

  bool isLoading = false;

  Future getUser () async {

    Response response;

    try {
      log("TryCatchCalled");

      response = await httpService!.getRequest("/b/BGT5");

      if(response.statusCode == 200){

        setState(() {

          userResponse = UserResponse.fromJson(response.data);

          user = userResponse!.user;

          log("ResponseStatusCode200 ${response.statusCode}");

        });

      }else{
        log("ResponseStatusCode ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      isLoading = false;
      log("GetUserResponseException ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    httpService = HttpService();
    userResponse = UserResponse();
    user = User();

    getUser();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("User Profile"),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          :  Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network(user!.avatar),
            Container(height: 16,),
            Text("Hello, ${user!.firstName} ${user!.lastName}")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting LateInitializationError: Field 'avatar' has not been initialized error

Below is what i have tried by changing my user class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User{

  @JsonKey(name: "id")
  int? id;

  @JsonKey(name: "email")
  String? email;

  @JsonKey(name: "first_name")
  String? firstName;

  @JsonKey(name: "last_name")
  String? lastName;

  @JsonKey(name: "avatar")
  String? avatar;

  User();

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

}
```

But when i do the above when i change class variables from late i get a new error Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
Image.network(user!.avatar),

below is the full error log

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building UserProfile(dirty, state: _UserProfileState#c6357):
LateInitializationError: Field 'avatar' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  UserProfile UserProfile:file:///C:/Users/Emman/AndroidStudioProjects/json_crud/lib/main.dart:28:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      User.avatar (package:json_crud/classes/user.dart)
#1      _UserProfileState.build (package:json_crud/screens/user_profile.dart:81:19)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4705:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4588:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4763:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4566:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4561:5)
...     Normal element mounting (169 frames)
#177    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3631:14)
#178    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6261:36)
#179    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6272:32)
...     Normal element mounting (391 frames)
#570    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3631:14)
#571    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3383:18)
#572    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1198:16)
#573    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1167:5)
#574    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1112:18)
#575    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2531:19)
#576    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1111:13)
#577    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:944:7)
#578    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:924:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
```

how can i solve this

Comment: you just need to handle the case where the avatar is null, cause it seems like it doesn't always have a value in your response. i.e `user!.avatar != null ? Image.network(user!.avatar) : Image.asset("assets/default_avatar.png)`

Comment: @omarhatem i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It says where the error after your changes comes from right there:

> type 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.

so when you type your variable `firstName` like this: `String? firstName;` then the compiler is totally happy with `firstName = null`.

When you type it like `String firstName;` then its type `"String"` _prevents it from ever becoming null.

Maybe you have somewhere typed what should be a `String?` (or fetched by an if) as `String`, f.e. in

`factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);`?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getUser` in your init method, but since it it's async and returns a Future, you need to **await** it. Otherwise your code will not have completed when your build method gets called and your variables are still set to their default values (which means your `late` variables have never been initialized on those instances and you get the error you see).

As you cannot use the `await` keyword in a method that is not itself `async` (and `initState` is not), you need to find a way around that. The most common is using a `FutureBuilder` widget.

You can find a good example of the general setup here: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)